# Why async await doesn't work with react navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation in react-native
I'm stuck in the issue of preventing multiple clicking.
I thought `async-await` makes function executes orderly, but it doesn't wait until functions finish their job.

If you have any idea of this, please leave your comments.

Here's my code.

```js
    moveToFavorite = async () => {
            const {fetching, ScreenActions, navigation, clicked} = this.props;
            const {push, navigate} = navigation;

            await navigation.setParams({clicked: true});

            const test = await navigation.getParam('clicked')
            console.log(test) // it should be true, but false

            if(!clicked) {
                await ScreenActions.stackScreen('favorite');
                !clicked ? await navigate('FavoriteScreen') : null;
                await ScreenActions.init_clicked();
                await navigation.setParams({clicked: false});
            }
        }
`
```

Comment: My guess is because you can't guarantee the things you're awaiting are actually promises in structure, so they're likely firing in a random order depending on execution time.

Comment: I don't think navigation.getParam('clicked') is an asynchronous function

Comment: @Gorbles, Thank you for the reply, then how can I prevent multiple clicking? Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @MingyuJeon - you could wrap all of those function calls in `async` wrappers, but that'd be a bit hacky. I recommend simply checking for a `clicked` prop at the start of the function, when inside that check setting the prop to `true`, and ending it after the actual asynchronous call (if that's `navigate`, I'm not sure). The prop will be set instantly, but it won't be unset until after the `await` resolves.